# command line arguments argv and argc

Tags: c, arguments, argv, argc

I understand that `argc` counts the number of arguments and `argv` takes in the argument, but is their a way I can determine if my argument from `argv` was inputted in a certain format like in parentheses and not in parenthesis. Such as `./a.out "Hello Word"` and `./a.out Hello World`?

Comment: First one will be only one argument. The second is two. The specific shell might add it's own quirks.

Comment: On most shell terminal such as bash, quotation are used to group together (as in, in a single argv) argument that contains whitespace (such as space and tabulation, normally used to separated argv arguments). Special characters are normally not kept in argv. If you want to use those special character as normal character, you need to use the escape character `\\`.

Comment: if you find out that one of the arguments contains spaces it certainly was passed in between parenthesis

Comment: This is a fundamental mistake made by early Unix shells, and unfortunately has to be perpetuated forever for compatibility. It is impossible for a program to get its command line before the shell messes with it in several ways. This should have been a library call rather than a permanent feature of the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Basically the only way to do this is to do a string comparison with a function like `strcmp`. However, one thing that complicates the matter is that the shell you are using might remove the quotes before your program has a chance to see them. To make things worse, how this is handled depends on the shell, so what works for one shell might fail for another one. Posix shells (sh, bash, ksh and so forth) handles quotes the same way and do not offer any way of detecting it.

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Number of arguments: %d\n", argc);
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
        printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

yields this output for an asterisk as argument when using the shell bash:

```
/tmp/test$ ./a.out *
Number of arguments: 3
Argument 0: ./a.out
Argument 1: a.out
Argument 2: main.c
```

This is because the `*` expands to all files in the current directory by the shell. Quotes usually group things that would otherwise be seen as two different arguments. If you want to pass quotes to bash you can escape them.

```
/tmp/test$ ./a.out "Hello world"
Number of arguments: 2
Argument 0: ./a.out
Argument 1: Hello world

/tmp/test$ ./a.out \"Hello world\"
Number of arguments: 3
Argument 0: ./a.out
Argument 1: "Hello
Argument 2: world"
```

So the answer is unfortunately no. There is no general method to do this. Some shells might provide tools to do this, but there is no guarantee for that, and even if they do, there is no standard way to do it.

Comment: Every Posix shell handles quoted arguments the same way. Of course, `cmd` is not a Posix shell, but on a unix-like system, you can expect the same behaviour.

Comment: @rici But as far as I know, there's no way to detect it? Right?

Comment: There is no way to detect it. No shell provides such a mechanism. It does not depend in the shell, within a Posix environment. Windows, of course, is different.